# ajax function starts after second click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, validation

I have a form connected with ajax request. I use validation jquery plugin for form check. 
So, when i click to submit button ajax call not work. After clicking submit button again it's working.
Why is this happening?

Here is my form

```
<form action="" id="anyQuestion" class="form-row">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="slug" value="{{$page->slug}}">
    <div class="form-group col-12">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-6">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="mail" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-6">
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="submit-button mb-4 mt-2 w-100">submit</button>
</form>
```

And my ajax function with validation

```
    $('#anyQuestion').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        phone: {
            required: true,
             minlength: 10
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        var anyQuestionForm = $('#anyQuestion');
        anyQuestionForm.submit(function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/xhr/anyquestion',
                data: anyQuestionForm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if( data == 'ok' ){
                       Swal.fire({
                           position: 'top-end',
                           type: 'success',
                           showConfirmButton: false
                         })
                       console.log(data);
                       document.getElementById("anyQuestion").reset();
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                      })
                },
            });
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why getting the form element while the `submitHandler` function passes the element as one of the arguments? `$("#myform").validate({ submitHandler: function(form) { form.submit(); } }); ` https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines:

```
    var anyQuestionForm = $('#anyQuestion');
    anyQuestionForm.submit(function (e) {
```

are in your submit handler, but they are what set up the submit handling in the first place. So, it seems your first button click is calling `submitHandler`, which is then setting up your form's submit event handler so that another click will submit the AJAX request.

They should be in a `document.ready()` function:

```
$(function(){
    var anyQuestionForm = $('#anyQuestion');
    anyQuestionForm.submit(function (e) { . . .
});
```

Or, since you have your `submit` callback already inside your `submitHandler`, you may not even need the `submit` callback and just go with:

```
submitHandler: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/xhr/anyquestion',
            data: anyQuestionForm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if( data == 'ok' ){
                   Swal.fire({
                       position: 'top-end',
                       type: 'success',
                       showConfirmButton: false
                     })
                   console.log(data);
                   document.getElementById("anyQuestion").reset();
                }
            },

            .   .   .
```